# How to repair a binary file (missing aproximately 10 hex values in 2000 possible positions)?

Tags: java, python, regex, image, binary

Alright, let's assume that a file has 2000 instances of \x0A, and 10 of those instances are directly preceded by \x0D. If any of the \x0D bits are deleted the file won't parse. If you deleted all 10 instances of \x0D from the file which are followed by \x0A would it be possible to put them back?

Some things that may help:

If the first instance of \x0D is found, the image (.gif or .png) will be partially visible, if your further find the second position, more of the image is revealed and so on, but it must be found in order (top to bottom).

In other words, you could technically repair the file by placing \x0d before each instance of \x0A in the file, and then deleting them sequentially until a block is solved, and more of the image becomes visible. The image would change once you clear all the extra \x0D bits before the correctly placed one. Then move on to the next block, and so on until all \x0D's are uncovered.

For example

```
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
```

Should be

```
x0A
x0A
\x0D\x0A
x0A
\x0D\x0A
```

If you sequentially remove all the \x0D bits, when your file looks like this:

```
x0A
x0A
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
\x0D\x0A
```

The image will change, then you can skip ahead one instance of \x0D\x0A and proceed until another image change occurs.

However, it would take time to test each position, meaning for this particular image if you kept a good pace and did it by hand, you could solve it in about 6 hours. Is there any way to write a script to do this?

This would enable recovery of .png and animated .gif files which were corrupted by being transferred in ascii mode.

In my example, trial and error would work if you could test if the image changes after each altercation (it will only change if you get the right position (as any incorrect position would render the remainder of the file unreadable). You'd need to try 2000 times, once per position and detect which 10 positions resulted in image changes.

If it's not possible to check, you could brute force it by trying all combinations (how long would this take) and checking if the entire file parsed correctly (somehow).

This is the example (broken) file, without any \x0D\x0A patterns: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4UcM.gif]

This is with one (the first) position solved:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf08g.gif]

Here is the original file (with the 10 correctly placed \x0D values):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrIEb.gif]

PLEASE help me solve the age old problem of broken ftp GIFs. This seems like a process that is doable.

zip file with 3 gifs (giphy is original, giphy 2 has the first 2 locations solved, giphy3 has no locations solved)

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=84665946797535126945

Comment: It sounds like, if you knew what part of the file structure was being corrupted, you could fix it without trial and error. What do you mean by "won't parse" and "partially visible"?

Comment: Yes, that would work. I could add an \x0D in front of every \x0A and remove them one by one until more and more of the image revealed itself. The file in the example is an animated gif. It will load/loop up until the point there is an incorrect \x0D. The progressive repair would be visible in applications like a browser, but wouldn't be able to fully parse (you'd get an error opening it in photoshop for example). The hard part is testing whether you get more of the gif after each change. You can clearly see it visually, but I'm not sure how you can write an app to test.

Comment: Something else that may help, the picture will ONLY visually change/update how it renders once you've solved a block if you remove \x0D one by one. As in, you have the first 2 blocks solved, you may get 2 frames of the animation, the animation will loop those two frames until you find the 3rd position and then loop 3 frames. The blocks don't need to be full frames, but you get the point. The animation/image should look the same until you've hit the correct block.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no distinguishable pattern for where the \x0Dx\0A pattern should show up that I can tell. Some Gif's (very small) may not have it occur at all. I tried search GIF documentation to find how they are placed, but didn't turn up anything. If a pattern does exist and can by exploited by a regex pattern, that would be a solution, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: The overall structure of GIF files can be used to try and decompose the file in its sections. If you run into a problem you can identify the section where CRs have been removed. Probing in the file *might* tell you where the next section begins, and this should be an indication of the number of CRs omitted from the previous section. This still leaves you with the problem of finding the LFs from where it was removed, although in a smaller section of the file. Possibly it *might* not be necessary to locate them exactly if you can tolerate minor errors in the image.

Comment: I haven't had any luck deconstructing the broken animation into layers. Image editors do not see it as an animated GIF without the 0D.  The image can survive if random bits get changed, but one 0D and the image is dead, which would lead me to believe it was part of the structure. However, I couldn't find any pattern from the hex, and some gif animations didn't even have a single 0D 0A in them. Other animations had the randomly occurring string in the middle of a layer. The Oprah example has them every few frames, but also seem randomly distributed. cont.

Comment: If it were possible to somehow scan through the file and find the static images and separate them into frames, then create a new GIF animation from them it could be a lossy solution (maybe). However I suspect sequentially brute forcing it would be more efficient, perhaps with some kind of OCR mechanism. All that needs to happen is it needs to identify if the image is rendered differently (further) from the last edit, that's the key.

Comment: I can't check up on the broken GIFs since they are even more severely damaged after downloading from the imgur site: there's a difference in byte 11 between the correct file and the file with a single fix (0x00 vs 0xff).

Comment: You're right, I know what the problem is. One sec. It's that stack overflow re-uploads them to i.stack.imgur.com

Comment: Fixed, they should all be identical except for the extra/lack of 0D bits

Comment: Well, they aren't - not after the download. You may have to convert to a hexdump and upload as ASCII text.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=84665946797535126945 .zip archive. I recreated the three gifs (working from the good image and then corrupting it). The first image giphy has all 10 locations correct, giphy2 has the first two locations correct and the rest blank, and giphy3 is blank on all 10.

Comment: OK - now they have almost equal file sizes, and a difference between the correct file and the one with one CRLF fixed appears before a LF. I've looked at the GIF format, and there's absolutely no redundancy in it; image data blocks don't even have markers. So I'd say that it is rather hopeless to try and find anything better than the trial-and-error method you have described.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, any ideas how to practically automate the trial and error approach?